# cannot find lib processing

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

Im trying to run eclipse on processing so i can export my sketch as a jar which can run on any operating system. But i'm getting the following error, Here i'm using an extension called proclisping. Has any one got suggestions why my lib cant be found? Im using processing 2. If anyone has any other way where i can get my scetches to run on any machine with all my images, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're trying to run Processing in Eclipse. Next, have you checked these [instructions](http://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/)? Finally, you may prefer the Eclipse plugin [proclipsing](http://code.google.com/p/proclipsing/) (**NOTE** currently proclipsing is BETA).

Comment: The proclipsing is exactly what i have been using.